# spring is not injecting my class

Tags: spring

I am getting null pointer exception when I am trying to use mathUtil instance because it is not getting injected. I think becan creation is success full but not injecting?

below is my class getting the error:

```
    package com.cts.mms.process.service
    @Component
    public class MocalMathVerifier implements MathVerifer {

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MocalMathVerifier .class);

        @Autowired
        MathUtil mathUtil;

        @Autowired
        mathLogger mathLogger;

public verifyMaths(){
       List<MathObject> mathObjList = mathUtil.getctList(mathList);

}
}
```

MY context.xml is as follows

```
<beans default-autowire="no"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:mmsogenmerfier.properties" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.mms.process"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <array>
                <value>com.cts.mms.process.oxm.metagen</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="25" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop> <prop key="mail.smtp.startssl.enable">true</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleMailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="from" value="${smtp.email.from}" />
        <property name="to" value="${smtp.email.to}" />
        <property name="subject" value="${smtp.email.subject}" />
        <!-- <property name="text" value ="${stmp.email.bodyText}"/> -->

        <property name="text">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            Dear %s,
            Mail Content : %s
        ]]>
    </value>
         </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Below is MathUtil class definition. removed the content from body  which think is not necessary here in the post.

```
package com.cts.mms.process.common;

@Component("mathUtil")
public class MathUtil { 

public List<MathObject> getctList(List<Maths> mathList) {


}
```

Below is how MocalMathVerifier is accessed

```
package com.cts.mms.process.service;
@Component
public class MathVerifierFactory {

public MathVerifer getMathVerifier(Short mathtypeId){

    if(mathtypeId==100 )
            return new MocalMathVerifier();

    }
}



package com.cts.mms.process.service;
@Component("verifier")
public class Verifier {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Verifier.class);
    @Autowired
    private MathVerifierFactory mathVerifierFactory;

public void verifyMathInfo() {

 mathVerifierFactory.getMathVerifier(mathId).verifyPaths(mathList);

}
```

Comment: I see a bunch of stuff that doesn't appear related, and essentially nothing that is. SSCCE please.

Comment: Yes, because I have18 classes and SMTP stuff, which I could not post everything here

Comment: Could you please add definitions of MathUtils and description of how you acquire an instance of MocalMathVerifier?

Comment: I'm saying to remove the stuff that isn't related.

Comment: @ Dave Newton, what do you mean by isn't related? related to this post or code. if it is code, yes everything is needed in my application.

Comment: @mahesh Your update answers only part of my question. Could you please share the way you acquire an instance of MocalMathVerifier ?

Comment: @IvanMushketyk, updated post as you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
if(mathtypeId==100 )
        return new MocalMathVerifier();

}
```

Spring IoC will be able to inject dependency into an object using Autowire only if the object is created using Spring IoC itself. If you are creating an object simply using

```
new MocalMathVerifier();
```

there is no way for Spring to find out that it is time to inject dependencies in the newly created object.

You can change the class in the following way:

```
@Component("verifier")
public class Verifier {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Verifier.class);
    @Autowired
    private MocalMathVerifier mathVerifier;

public void verifyMathInfo() {

 mathVerifier.verifyPaths(mathList);

}
```

As you can see, now you asks Spring to create your dependency (mathVerifier). When Spring will create (inject) it, it will also inject its dependencies (mathUtil, mathLogger).

If factory contains some logic of selecting/creating an instance of MathVerifier, you still have plenty of options. You can Autowire factory in your Verifier class and in MathVerifierFactory Autowire all possible instances of MathVerifiers. It will be something like:

```
class MathVerifierFactory {
    @Autowired
    MocalMathVerifier mocalMathVerifier;

    @Autowired
    SomeOtherMathVerifier someOtherMathVerifier;

    public MathVerifer getMathVerifier(Short mathtypeId){

         if(mathtypeId==100 )
            return mocalMathVerifier;    
         } else {
            return someOtherMathVerifier;
         }
     }
}
```

But beware that in this case you may end up sharing same instances of MathVerifiers between different clints, that can create problems with shared state and concurrency.

Another option will be to inject MathUtil and MathLogger into a factory and create  MathVerifier instances, manually:

```
class MathVerifierFactory {
    @Autowired
    MathUtil mathUtil;

    @Autowired
    MathLogger mathLogger;

    public MathVerifer getMathVerifier(Short mathtypeId){

         if(mathtypeId==100 )
            return new MocalMathVerifier(mathUtil, mathLogger);    
         } else {
            return new SomeOtherMathVerifier(mathLogger);
         }
     }
}
```

The problem with the last approach is that different subclasses of MathVerifier can have different dependencies, you may need all of them in MathVerifierFactory which can be not a good design decision. What you could do instead is to create a separate factory class for each subtype of MathVerifier. It will be something like this:

```
class MocalMathVerifierFactory {
    @Autowired
    MathUtils mathUtils;

    @Autowired
    MathLogger mathLogger;

    MocalMathVerifier createMathVerifier() {
         return new MocalMathVerifier(mathUtils, mathLogger);
    }
}

class SomeOtherMathVeriferFactory {
    @Autowired
    MathLogger mathLogger;

    MocalMathVerifier createMathVerifier() {
         return new MocalMathVerifier(mathLogger);
    }
}

class MathVerifierFactory {
    @Autowired
    MocalMathVerifierFactory mocalMathVerifierFactory;

    @Autowired
    SomeOtherMathVerifierFactory someOtherMathVerifierFactory;

    public MathVerifer getMathVerifier(Short mathtypeId){

         if(mathtypeId==100 )
            return mocalMathVerifierFactory.createMathVerifier();    
         } else {
            return someOtherMathVerifier.createMathVerifier();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks IvanMushketyk. But here I don't know which class will be called, because MathVerifierFactory factory class has more 7 classes similar to  MocalMathVerifier. I was returing the correct class instance based on mathId passed to factory method. I think I may need to use spring autowired for all classes being instantiated in the MathVerifierFactory  class in it self?

Comment: @mahesh I've updated my answer with few recipes for your case.

Comment: Thank you @ IvanMushketyk, I got your point. I am not sure if declaring  all the 8 classes as with @autowired in the MathVerifierFactory class is good practice? isn't or there is any other ways.

Comment: It very much depends on your task. It may be good, it may be not. If I knew more about your design problem I would suggest some specific ways. Maybe you can use less factories or you could use approach number 1 or 2 or some combination of my advices. Anyway we identified the main source of your problem and now you can build some solution around the correct principle.

Comment: @mahesh If you want some help with your design problem, you can create a new question. If you think that I helped with your original problem, please mark my answer as accepted.